# Checking error level while building with sbt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sbt, errorlevel

I want to write a windows `.cmd` script that publishing all project modules into local repository. But I want to stop at first error that may be occur. I'm checking `%ERRORLEVEL%` but it's always equals to 0 even if `sbt publish-local` command fails with some error.

```
@echo on
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansions

set modules=^
    sbt-common^
    common^             

for %%A in (%modules%) do (
    echo ======================================
    echo =          PUBLISHING %%A            =
    echo ======================================
    cd %%A
    call sbt publish-local              
    echo %ERRORLEVEL%       :: <- Always = 0
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
)

:error
@endlocal
exit /B 1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo on
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set modules=^
    sbt-common^
    common^             

for %%A in (%modules%) do (
    echo ======================================
    echo =          PUBLISHING %%A            =
    echo ======================================
    cd %%A
    call sbt publish-local              
    echo !ERRORLEVEL!
    if !ERRORLEVEL! geq 1 goto error
)

:error
@endlocal
exit /B 1
```

Note that `EnableDelayedExpansion` should not have a following s, and you should use `!` instead of `%` inside parenthesis in batch.

Comment: You do not need two `setlocal` lines, just one with the correct keyword (the first one is wrong!)...

Comment: You're right, I was still editing it and forgot to remove it.